# 301 redirects for individual pages in Office 365

Tags: office-365, dns, 301

Is it possible to do 301 redirects in Office 365.

Suppose i have page1.aspx, and i am going to delete that page.

I want all the users and search engine bots to do a 301 redirection to a new page page2.aspx.

Is this possible in Office 365? I know that with SharePoint 2010, I can do changes to the IIS or write a custom component that does the redirection for me.

But not sure how to do it in Office 365.

Javascript redirects are not an option.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that's one of the limitations of Office 365 SharePoint Online. You neither have access to IIS settings nor can you deploy a server-side component to redirect to another page with an HTTP 301 or 302.